# doubt with unequal induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Show that for all n ≥ 2 it is verified:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+ ...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{n} $$

I have used the induction method to arrive at the following result:

$$\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}>\sqrt{k+1} $$

someone can help me, I think I have not solved it well

Comment: $\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\color{red}{>}\sqrt{k+1}$.

Comment: Why is this term $(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ different than all the other terms?

Comment: Wait have you *proven* $\sqrt{k} + \frac 1{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$ and are asking how to use that result to prove $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}})+(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})+ ...+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) > \sqrt{n}$ in induction proof?  Or have you determined that *if* you can prove  $\sqrt{k} + \frac 1{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$ that will allow you to do the induction so you are asking how to *prove*  $\sqrt{k} + \frac 1{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$ in the first place?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} = \sqrt{1}$.  Did you mean for all $n > 1$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sry for all n > 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ... is enough.

If you have proven that $\sqrt{k} + \frac {1}{\sqrt{k+1}} > \sqrt{k+1}$

Then you can state that for $\frac 1{\sqrt 1} + \frac 1{\sqrt 2} =\sqrt{1} + \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} > \sqrt{2}$, so the base step of the induction is done.

You can state if you know $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + .... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} > \sqrt j$

Then $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + .... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}) + \frac 1{\sqrt{j+1}} >$

$(\sqrt{j})+ \frac 1{\sqrt{j+1}}>$

$\sqrt {j+1}$.

So the induction step holds.

So it has been successfully proven by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Although the following is not strictly based on induction (i.e., other than use of telescoping series), I thought it might be instructive to present a direct proof of the coveted inequality.

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}\right)\tag{telescoping  series}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}\tag{rationalizing numerator}\\\\
&<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt k}\tag{For $k>1$, $\sqrt{k-1}> 0$}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
k>0\\
k^2+k> k^2 \\
\sqrt{k(k+1)} > k \\
\sqrt{k(k+1)}+1 > k+1 \\
\sqrt{k} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}> \sqrt{k+1} \\
\end{eqnarray*}